# Return values of a list for specific list of indices from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list with specific indices

```
list1 = [0,3,5]
```

and another list.

```
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

I want a single line code to return items of list2 for indices mentioned in list1.

```
output = ['a','d','f']
```

I know its possible from ***comprehensive for loop*** with/without ***lambda function*** or something.

Attempts I was trying were something like below

```
[x for x in list2[y] if y in list1]
[m for m in list2 for f in list1]
[for x in i: list2[x]]
```

None of the attempts gave me expected results.

Please let me know how to achieve this!

Comment: no need for a lambda function `[list2[i] for i in list1]`

Comment: Been attempting from last half an hour. Just dont want to use `for x in list1 : return list2[x]`

Comment: The please [edit] your question to include your attempts.

Comment: attempts added. Can the question be *un-downvoted* now. I couldnt find the exact question after search. and it was confusing for me and I was stuck

Comment: I didn't vote, but they probably won't be. It might be a good time to read [ask] so that future questions are more well received: providing a [mcve], to include what you've tried to solve the problem, is almost always a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `list-comprehension`:

```
[list2[i] for i in list1]
#['a', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to be doing a lot of indexing like this, I would recommend using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), since [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) makes tasks like this very simple (and fast):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list1 = np.array([0,3,5]) 
>>> list2 = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
>>> list2[list1]

['a' 'd' 'f']
```

This indexing will outperform list comprehensions, here are the timings:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: l1 = np.random.randint(10000, size=500)

In [3]: l2 = np.random.randint(10, size=10000)

In [4]: %timeit [l2[i] for i in l1]
106 µs ± 1.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit l2[l1]
3.6 µs ± 95.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Not lot of indexing , I just thought list comprehension would be clean and quicker(not sure)

Comment: Cool. I upvoted although @Joe Iddon 's answer I was looking for

Comment: @Prateek his answer is clean and simple, just wanted to add my 2 cents.  Happy programming!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
list1 = [0,3,5]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

print(list(map(lambda x:list2[x],list1)))
```

output:

```
['a', 'd', 'f']
```